# How do you call a suspend function inside a SAM?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to create a `Flow` that needs to emit values from a callback but I can't call the `emit` function since the SAM is a normal function

Here's the class with the SAM from a library that I can't really modify it the way I need it to be.

```
class ValueClass {

    fun registerListener(listener: Listener) {
        ...
    }    

    interface Listener {
        fun onNewValue(): String
    }
}
```

And here's my take on creating the `Flow` object

```
class MyClass(private val valueClass: ValueClass) {
    fun listenToValue = flow<String> {
        valueClass.registerListener { value ->
            emit(value) // Suspension functions can only be called on coroutine body
        }
    }
}
```

I guess it would've been simple if I could change the `ValueClass` but in this case, I can't. I've been wrapping my head around this and trying to look for implementations.

At least from what I know so far, one solution would be to use `GlobalScope` like this

```
class MyClass(private val valueClass: ValueClass) {
    fun listenToValue = flow<String> {
        valueClass.registerListener { value ->
            GlobalScope.launch {
                emit(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works but I don't want to use `GlobalScope` since I'll be using `viewModelScope` to tie it to my app's lifecycle.

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html look useful?

Comment: Oh my god yes! Thank you so much! Gonna try it out and hopefully it works

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am wondering the same.

Comment: I used `callbackFlow` like @stkent mentioned and instead of `emit`, you `offer` the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`callbackFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) to create a `Flow` from the callback. It will look something like:

```
fun listenToValue(): Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
    valueClass.registerListener { value ->
        trySend(value)
        channel.close() // close channel if no more values are expected
    }
    awaitClose { /*unregister listener*/ }
}
```

Or if only one value is expected from the callback, you can use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html?query=inline%20suspend%20fun%20%3CT%3E%20suspendCancellableCoroutine(crossinline%20block:%20(CancellableContinuation%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20Unit):%20T). It this case `listenToValue()` function must be `suspend` and later called from a coroutine(e.g. [`someScope.launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html)):

```
suspend fun listenToValue(): String = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    valueClass.registerListener { value ->
        continuation.resumeWith(value)
    }
}
```